# Automated framework for lighthouse testing?

Tags: node.js, lighthouse

Tried to have urls in one text document and script in batch file as in the below link but it is producing different results when compared to the results produced when i perform it in chrome.

https://medium.com/@giezendanenner/running-lighthouse-reports-on-the-command-line-1691a1b06a56

This is the script in batch file.

```
@For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("./urls.txt"
) Do @LightHouse "%%A" --quiet --chrome-flags="--headless"  --throttling-method=provided   --disable-storage-reset=true  --view ----output-path "C:\Users\sujith\Desktop\test.html" --only-categories=accessibility,performance
```

Comment: In chrome audits these were my settings: Device:Desktop, Audits:performance,accessibility , Throttling:no-throttling and no clear storage.

Comment: So i want automated script also according to above settings.

Comment: How drastically different were the results? Could you give a little clarity on the result via the tool vs the result manually via chrome?

Comment: When using chrome dev tools its giving accessibility 91 and through command line its 95.There is also another issue that the pages after login are not loading for producing results.I tried using --extra-headers also.